# Is there an way to calculate the value of O(n)

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

Is there an way to calculate the value of O(n) (Big Oh)? I understand it's use in algorithm. But my question is how is the value calculated?

Comment: It is a class of sequences, those which are functions of $n$ such that $f(n) \le Cn$ for some constant $C$ and all sufficiently large $n$.  The "value" is defined and needs no "calculation".

Answer (score 1):

$O(n)$ is the set of all functions $f$ satisfying $|f(n)|\leq C|n|$ for some constant $C>0$ and all $n$ greater than some $N$.

Being that it is a set of functions, it does not have a "value", nor does it make sense to "compute" it.

**Addendum**: perhaps you are asking the following: how do I count the work done in an algorithm? This might be better suited for [cstheory.stackexchange.com](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com). You might also have a crack at reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it).

Comment: I am looking to calculate  the 2nd formula mentioned in "Extensions and generalizations" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations. How do I calculate it?

Comment: @Chachili: I would ask that specific question on cstheory.stackexchange.com. Experts in CS hang out there.

Comment: The formula is nlogn+(m-1)*nloglogn+O(n)  - this need to have a definite value because for m=1 and n=6 this is supposed to give the answer of 14.7

Answer (score 1):

The [Landau symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) $O(n)$ in a formula, like the appearance you're pointing to in a comment, is *not something you can calculate*.

Rather, $O(n)$ is a *placeholder* for "here is something that we're not bothering to specify explicitly, but we *will* tell you that it grows no faster than $n$ does, or at most some fixed constant times $n$".

So an expression involving $O(\cdots)$ gives only partial information about the function it describes; it does not contain enough information to compute its exact value.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate and understand your explanation. But if this is the case, how do we prove O(1) to be constant? Does it have  a known value?

Comment: @Chachili: $O(1)$ is also a placeholder -- it means "here is something else we're not telling you what is (and it can be a function of your variable too), but we do promise you it is at least _bounded_". It is not necessarily strictly constant. For example a $\sin(n)$ term might be one possible term that can be abbreviated as $O(1)$.